# ggplot facet grid y axis some values are not visible how adjust grid

Tags: r, ggplot2

ggplot2 i am trying plot the scatter plot but and merging with facet grid some values are looking incomplete near y axis points how to fix this anyone help me.

```
dummy <- data.frame(Value = c(rnorm(100, mean = 35, sd = 2),
                              rnorm(100, mean = 47, sd = 2),
                              rnorm(100, mean = 28, sd = 1)),
                    Method = c(rep("base", times = 100),
                               rep("new", times = 100),
                               rep("edge", times = 100)),
                    Subject = rep(paste0("M", seq_len(100)), times = 3))


library("ggplot2")
ggplot(dummy, aes(y=Value, x=Subject)) +
  geom_point(aes(shape=Method),size = 2.5) +
  facet_wrap(~ Method)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Although using the `expand` parameter would be the textbook answer, the sanest way to do this with the given data is to make `Subject` a numeric variable instead of a factor. If you don't do this, your x axis labels will be hopelessly overlapped, and your underlying panel grid will look weird.

Compare `Subject` as numeric:

```r
ggplot(dummy, aes(y = Value, x = as.numeric(gsub("M", "", Subject)))) +
  geom_point(aes(shape=Method),size = 2.5) +
  facet_wrap(~ Method) +
  labs(x = "Subject")
```

[image]

Versus as a character with `expand`:

```r
ggplot(dummy, aes(y = Value, x = Subject)) +
  geom_point(aes(shape = Method),size = 2.5) +
  facet_wrap(~ Method) +
  scale_x_discrete(expand = c(0.1, 0.1))
```

[image]

I think it's pretty clear that the numeric version is easier to read.

Answer (score 2):

You can increase the margin of the X axis with ggplot2::scale_x_discrete(), just experiment with the "add = 5" until you have what you need

```
library("ggplot2")

ggplot2::ggplot(dummy, aes(y=Value, x=Subject)) +
  ggplot2::geom_point(aes(shape=Method),size = 2.5) +
  ggplot2::scale_x_discrete(expand = expand_scale(add = 5)) +
  ggplot2::facet_grid(~ Method, scales = "free")
```